# Confused about Flow typing with React Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, flowtype, flow-typed

I am a bit confused which flow types to use with react components
here part of my code:

```
// @flow
import React from 'react';
import Stage from '../../../shared/sections/Stage';

interface WithContent {
  content: any,
}

class DynamicContent extends React.PureComponent {
  props: {
    content: [],
  };

  static componentsMap = {
    dn_module_stage: Stage,
  };

  static getComponent(identifier: string): ?React$Element<WithContent> {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(DynamicContent.componentsMap, identifier)) {
      return DynamicContent.componentsMap[identifier];
    }
    return null;
  }

  static renderComponent(component: GenericComponent, key: number): ?React$Element<WithContent> {
    const Component: any = DynamicContent.getComponent(component.type);
    if (Component) {
      return <Component key={key} content={component.content} />;
    }
    return null;
  }
  ...
  ...
```

probably the interface is unnecessary and I should just use ?React$Element<*>, right?
I am trying to type this line but with no success, what should I use instead of any?

```
const Component: any = DynamicContent.getComponent(component.type);
```

Are there good sources for correct usage of flow with react? I just found one article and the official docu which is not much. Any github repos with code examples?

Answer (score 1):

You could check the flux repo on Github which has flow used in the code. For example, https://github.com/facebook/flux/blob/master/examples/flux-async/src/views/AppView.js